# Is this question about device color calibration on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

The question: [How do I convert the color space correctly?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/74962/how-do-i-convert-the-color-space-correctly)

I have a hard time understanding even what this question is about, which doesn't necessarily mean it's off topic here - but sometimes can indicate that.

- Is this question on topic here?
- How is it or isn't it?
- Do we have past precedence in meta about this area? (I'm not just looking for old questions to prove that this is now on topic)

Answer (score 4):

My vote would be yes.  It's a bit technical, but it's the digital equivalent of some of the finer points of color exposure in film development.  I wouldn't strongly object if the community decided no as well, but I'd personally vote in favor of it being on topic.